# Illegal destination address sms manager shared preferences

Tags: java, android

I am using numbers stored in shared preferences to send text messages but when i run the app it crashes and the logcat says there is an illegal destination address how?

here is my logcat

```
12-30 21:01:30.758 12239-12239/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.android.beez.help2, PID: 12239
                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress
                                                   at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:127)
                                                   at com.android.beez.help2.MainActivity.sendSms(MainActivity.java:63)
                                                   at com.android.beez.help2.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:41)
                                                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
                                                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18790)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and here is my

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.android.beez.help2;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button button;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonInit();
    Button setupMa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setupMA);
    setupMa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Setup.class);
            startActivity(a);
        }
    });


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            loadCredit();
            sendSms();

        }
    });
}


protected void sendSms() {

    spInit();

    String number1 = sharedPreferences.getString("first", "");
    String number2 = sharedPreferences.getString("second", "");
    String number3 = sharedPreferences.getString("third", "");
    String name = sharedPreferences.getString("name", "");
    String text = "Help, this is " + name + ", if you are reading this I am in trouble please help me" +
            " Iam located at " + "http://www.google.com/maps/place/"+GPSTracker.latitude+","+GPSTracker.longitude+ " " +
            "" +
            "" +
            "-Sent via the Emergency App";

    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    manager.sendTextMessage(number1, null, text, null, null);
    manager.sendTextMessage(number2, null, text, null, null);
    manager.sendTextMessage(number3, null, text, null, null);



    boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

    if (isFirstRun) {
        Intent launchSetups = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Setup.class);
        startActivity(launchSetups);


        }
    }

protected void loadCredit() {

    spInit();

    String creditLine = sharedPreferences.getString("dialLoadSp","");

    Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:"+creditLine);
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, number);
    startActivity(callIntent);
}

public void buttonInit() {
     button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_main);
}
public void spInit() {
    sharedPreferences = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("com.android.beez.help2",MODE_PRIVATE);

}

}
```

The numbers the messages are being sent to are from editTexts and are the stored in sharedPreferences. could the problem be from shared preferences or is it and issue of the text manager

Comment: did u check for if there’s any space?

Comment: @Md.ibrahimkhalil any space where?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should specify the `destination address` add an if... `if(num1!="" || num2!="" || num3...)
manager.sendText...`

Comment: the destination address is specified. its whatever numbers are stored  stored in the shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I know this one :) Hope I'm not to late.

`IllegalArgumentException` is thrown if `destinationAddress` or `text` are empty.
In your case, you have this `String number1 = sharedPreferences.getString("first", "");` which means that your `number1` is empty at first run of the app, and therefore you get that exception.
Also you didn't provide full code here, where you said that numbers would be fill from edit text.